# How to add a custom button to a UINavigationBar (a la Foursquare)

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Im going through the different options of creating a custom UINavigationBar and since my app is iOS 5+, i am using this code:

```
// Set the background image all UINavigationBars
[[UINavigationBar appearance]  setBackgroundImage:NavigationPortraitBackground 
                                    forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Now i want a custom image button on the very right side and am a bit lost. Should I go another way, subclass UINavigationBar and add a button to it or would there be an easier way?

Comment: no i am not, i managed to set a rightBarButtonItem but i cant set the positioning so im not having much luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely subclass this thing.  UINavigationBar is easy to subclass, but very hard to put into a navigation controller.  I will show you my subclass (CFColoredNavigationBar), which also comes with an arbitrarily colored background for free.

```
//.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CFColoredNavigationBar : UINavigationBar

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *barBackgroundColor;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *postButton;
@end
//.m
#import "CFColoredNavigationBar.h"

@implementation CFColoredNavigationBar
@synthesize barBackgroundColor = barBackgroundColor_;
@synthesize postButton = postButton_;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    postButton_ = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.frame)-60, 0, 60.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.frame))];
    [postButton_ setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Post.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self addSubview:postButton_];
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if (barBackgroundColor_ == nil) {
        barBackgroundColor_ = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [barBackgroundColor_ CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectInset(self.frame, 0, self.frame.size.height*-2));
}

@end
```

Comment: best part, this thing is OS version agnostic.  Should work all the way back to 2.0

Comment: right now i have my custom nav bar set from a nib so initWithFrame wont get called. How could i do this in that respect? Or if you could share how you implemented your custom nav bar in your nav controller that'd be great too :)

Comment: use the code I provided in initWithNibName: and move it into awakeFromNib.  Simple!  And my approach was xib based too.  I'll edit this in.

Comment: Of course.  Figured it out myself after much trial and error, may as well let future visitors not have to.

Comment: I'm still confused, how do I set this custom navigation bar as the navigation bar for a navigation controller?